# Wordpress ajax request return 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Hello I have a problem with wordpress I can not get an ajax call and I can not find the reason. My query returns me all the time 0.

my javascript code :

updateButton.onclick = function (e) {

```
var donne = {
'action': 'my_action',
'lodges': updateDeleteArray
};

$(function () {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: donne,
url: ajaxurl,
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
console.log(data);
                },
            });
        });
};
```

my php code :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action',        'my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');

function my_action() {
    echo 'salut';
    die();
}
```

Comment: You looked in your development tool, which is being sent by ajax, what parameters are sent? You can try with the development tool of -> "network"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting `contentType` and `dataType`, because you are not returning a JSON into your function.

Or

modify your function like this

```
function my_action() {
    echo json_encode('salut');
    die();
}
```

hope it helps